# How to add particular class to li? ngTagsInput in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have a list of **li** items created by [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) I want to add selected class to specific li item who is by some means **irrelevant**.

Can anyone help? if you want me to elaborate this question I will, don't vote this question down.

Comment: check the `tagClass` in [documentation](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if u have solved the problem but I what I do is this:

template.html

```
<tags-input name="developer" ng-model="developer" placeholder="designer" 
class="tagDev"></tags-input>
```

css

```
.tagDev .tags .tag-item{
background: (color) !important;
color: white;
border: 1px solid (color);
}
```

Hope it be useful!

If u want to do more tags-input just use class and .class .tags. tag-item{style}